# How do you convert information from rle into a data frame

Tags: r

I want to convert the information contained in a the "rle" function in R, into a data frame, but couldn't find how. For example, for the vector

`x <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4)`

I want a dataframe that has two columns of `1 2 3 4` and `3 2 1 3`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted so much. It's not the most obvious thing....

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `unclass` to remove the `rle` class. Then you can just use `data.frame` on the resulting list.

```
data.frame(unclass(rle(x)))
##   lengths values
## 1       3      1
## 2       2      2
## 3       1      3
## 4       3      4
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it direclty with the `data.frame` function. `rle` actually returns a list of two components (`lengths` and `values`).

```
rleX
data.frame(values = rleX$values, lengths = rleX$lengths)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this simple function to convert to dataframe

```
data <- with(rle(x), data.frame(values, lengths))
```

Comment: This is nice if you want also to capture the names of the values where the rle categories switch:  data <- with(rle(x), data.frame(values, lengths, names(lengths))

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data.frame(table(x))

  x Freq
1 1    3
2 2    2
3 3    1
4 4    3
```

Comment: It's a nice solution for the provided data set but `rle != table` and this won't work in more complicated cases such as `set.seed(123) ; x <- sample(4, 10, replace = TRUE)`, for example. The other solution is the way to go probably.